# [WinError 123} Can't install pip packages

Tags: python

I tried to find solutions on simillar threads but really can't find any.
Can't install packages due to an error WinError 123 as shown on image below:
[Image here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2DzL.png)

I find it weird that in path there is 'sC' term at the end.

I tried to reinstall and install different versions of python but it happens on all as I assumme that is a Windows problem.

[ENV definitions pt.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HukM.png)

[ENV definitons pt.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpEys.png)

During investigation i put print command in path and mkdir function variable called 'name'. Everything goes well over there but i found a problem at last few lines:
[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l09Jr.png)
So the last Path is corrupted as it adds a 's' character and repeats the path again, and when tool is cropping the path it leaves it with just sC signs.

Comment: My guess is that you have a screw-up in your PATH environment variable.  Try `Get-ChildItem -Path Env:\PATH`.  You can use the control panel to fix the problem.

Comment: All of my PATH seems to be okay. C:\Users\bolec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\
That's a one example. I look at other and no signs of screwed-up PATH variables

Comment: Why don't you post the exact values of the PATH and PYTHONPATH variables?

Comment: I've added values and some investiagtion about 'sC' characters.

Comment: You have Python 3.9, Python 3.10, and Python 3.11 on your path.  That's not healthy, although that's not the problem here.  You are investigating in the right direction here; you just need to trace backwards to find out where that bad string comes from.

Comment: `python -m pip install numpy` can you try this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... it took rather longer distance than i thought and of course the answer is simple.

Easiest way is to run:

```
pip config debug
```

and localize your installing paths:

Here is the output:

[image: Here it is.]

I saw there was a weird one over there at `global.target` variable which I did not modify. Easy solution, just change `pip.ini` file so the path is actually the path you want your libraries to be stored at.